# vLookup as formula for conditional formatting in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, conditional-formatting

I'l trying to create a calendar that is similar to a K-12 school district calendar.

I have two tabs in Google Sheets.

Sheet1:

- Column A lists every date of the school year - it is formatted at mm/dd/yyyy.
- In Column B I have manually entered 1 of 5 "Events" associate with each date: "4-hour school day", "Basketball practice", "Basketball Game", "Weekend", and "No School".

Sheet2 is my calendar:

- Columns A3:G41 and K3:Q42 are formatted with dates. Date is formatted with just the day of the week. I'd like the cells in Sheet2 to be conditionally formatted based on their date, the date in Column A of Sheet1, and the Event from Column B of Sheet1.

Is this possible?

Here is the link to my spreadsheet, if it helps: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1exyzi2GkyVUkRzAxHvuyWVdVNv2U1LRQmvOUZIHm5ZU/edit#gid=321190736

Thanks!

I've tried looking around other stackoverflow tutorials but it doesn't look like any have this same issue.

Answer (score 1):

*You may try this within conditional format. rules:*

***Apply to range:*** `A1:Q`

***Custom formula is:*** `=vlookup(A1,indirect("Sheet1!A:B"),2,)="No School"`

- *Replicate the same with 4 other events by changing the `event name` within the formula*

[image]